# Why do hats sometimes randomly appear?

Tags: team-fortress-2

A couple of day's ago a YouTuber called "Muselk" uploaded a Team Fortress 2 video where around the 1 minute 30 seconds mark you can see a random hat just 'fly' out of his character.

I have had similar experiences before but mainly shrugged it off as a 'feature'.
What exactly causes this to happen?

Comment: It is [St.Patricks day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Patrick%27s_Day), it might have something to do with that

Comment: @Burgi but the video was uploaded on March 14th.

Comment: I didn't notice that...

Comment: TF2 isn't exactly the most bug-free game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some backstory on the related feature first:** they patched the game to make it so that certain hats "fall off" (some stay on the newly created ragdoll's head) upon a player death.

As Valve does when updating TF2, they broke this purely cosmetic feature, then fixed it, then broke it again (this was around 2013.)

**My experience:** Having played TF2 since release, I've seen exactly what you are talking about as a hat flying across the map when a player is killed by an explosion/other high impact method. Much like in the video you posted, sometimes client-side or server-side lag/delay will cause the hat from a just killed player to fly out of the ground.

Ironically, a [Steam Community post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/440/discussions/0/540744934469521825/?l=czech) on this exact phenomenon even references being an Engie and seeing it often... Probably due to the opportunity to be more observant than most when playing as Engie! :P

**The short of it:** This "bug" is almost certainly lag related. It has not been (as far as I know) an [officially documented glitch](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Glitches) and due to it happening only due to lag, it probably never will.